# How to check if a nested key is available or not in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have the below JavaScript object.

If `myobject` holds the below content, how do I check if a particular key is available or not?

```
{
    "AccountNbr": "1234567890123445",
    "AccountName": "Test Bob",
    "Address": {
        "addressId": 1234,
        "line1": "Sample Line 1",
        "line2": "Sample Line 2",
        "city": "Sample City",
        "state": "State"
    }
}
```

For example, to check if key `"AccountNbr"` is available. I used the below statement and it returned true.

```
"AccountNbr" in myobject
```

and it returned `true`. If I have to check if key `"addressId"` is available, I used the below statement and it returns false, though the key is available.

```
"Address.addressId" in myobject
```

The above statement always returns `false`, though `addressId` is available. Is there any other alternative to check if `addressId` is available?

I also tried giving `myobject.Address.addressId` and it always returned false, though the key is available.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
if('addressId' in myobject.Address){

}
```

Even better might be:

```
if('Address' in myObject && 'addressId' in myObject.Address){

}
```

This is the syntax that in uses, it basically checks if a certain key is among one of the keys in the object referred to in after the word `in`.

So you ask `if 'aPotentialKey' is one of the Object.keys(myObject)`?

`Object.keys(anObject)` will return an array of the keys in an object and if you wanted I guess you could do a for loop through those and check if its equal. But just a nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized way to do this:

```js
// function for checking whether an object contains a series of properties
function hasMember(object, propertyPath) {
  var result = propertyPath.split('.').reduce(function(last, next) {
    return {
      value: last.value && last.value[next],
      hasProperty: last.value && next in last.value
    };
  }, {
    value: object,
    hasProperty: true
  });
  
  return result.hasProperty;
}

// example scenario
var o = {
  "AccountNbr": "1234567890123445",
  "AccountName": "Test Bob",
  "Address": {
    "addressId": 1234,
    "line1": "Sample Line 1",
    "line2": "Sample Line 2",
    "city": "Sample City",
    "state": "State"
  }
};

console.log(hasMember(o, 'AccountNbr'));        // true
console.log(hasMember(o, 'Address.addressId')); // true
console.log(hasMember(o, 'Address.line3'));     // false
```